# Writing a stream to excel file

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-poi

In the below code i have streamed in data from an excel spreadsheet and grouped it, my question is how do i export each grouped stream to an excel file?

```
package excelgroupdata;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;


import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelGroupData {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
//create a input stream for your excel file from which data will be read.  
    FileInputStream excelSheetInput = new FileInputStream("C:/test1.xlsx");
    //POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(excelSheetInput);
    XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelSheetInput);
    //get first work sheet in your excel file.
    Sheet sheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
    //we will read data in first rows(0) second column(1)
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    Row myRow = sheet.getRow(1);
    Cell myCell= myRow.getCell(0);
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator ;
    String firstCell = myCell.getStringCellValue();
    int count =1;
    String nextCell;
    String Matter = "Matter Number: "+firstCell;
    System.out.println(Matter);
    while(rowIterator.hasNext())
    {


        myRow = sheet.getRow(count);
        cellIterator = myRow.cellIterator();
        myCell= myRow.getCell(0);
        nextCell= myCell.getStringCellValue();


        if(nextCell.equals(firstCell))
        {

            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                            switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
            System.out.println();
            count++;

        }
        else
        {          
            myRow = sheet.getRow(count);
            myCell= myRow.getCell(0);
            nextCell=myCell.getStringCellValue();
            firstCell=nextCell;
            Matter = "Matter Number: "+firstCell;
            System.out.println(Matter);
        }

    }


}
}
```

I am aware that there are some incorrectly coded elements but that is not of concern at the moment, the general idea works.

here is the data i stream in and how the grouped output looks:

```
Matter Number: A4041222
A4041222        Sihlaba     2011/09/16      2013/09/15      2012/11/20      
Matter Number: A4041231
A4041231        Gwavu       2011/09/26      2013/09/26      2012/11/22      
Matter Number: A4041260
A4041260        Lin         2011/11/21      2013/11/20      2012/11/29      
A4041260        Lin         2011/09/16      2013/09/15      2012/11/29      
Matter Number: A4041281
A4041281        Sharma      2011/09/16      2013/09/15      2013/01/21      
Matter Number: A4041336
A4041336        Nkwankwana  2011/09/16      2013/09/15      2013/01/21      
A4041336        Nkwankwana  2011/09/16      2013/09/15      2013/01/21      
Matter Number: A4041420
A4041420        Gqozo       2011/09/22      2013/09/21      2012/07/18      
A4041420        Gqozo       2011/09/22      2013/09/21      2012/07/20      
Matter Number: A4041494
A4041494        Henneberry  2011/09/21      2013/09/20      2013/01/21      
Matter Number: A4041522
A4041522        Monepya     2011/09/16      2013/09/15      2013/01/21      
Matter Number: A4041600
A4041600        Vezi        2011/09/16      2013/09/15      2012/12/13      
Matter Number: A4041640
A4041640        Cupido      2011/09/27      2013/09/26      2012/09/25      
A4041640        Cupido      2011/09/26      2013/09/25      2012/11/27      
Matter Number: A4041644
A4041644        Mfingwana   2011/09/27      2013/09/26      2013/01/21      
A4041644        Mfingwana   2011/09/27      2013/09/27      2013/01/21      
Matter Number: A4041665
A4041665        Mafura      2011/09/29      2013/09/28      2012/12/13      
Matter Number: A4041770
A4041770        Mlangeni    2011/09/17      2013/09/16      2012/10/12      
Matter Number: A4041965
A4041965        Vukeya      2011/09/17      2013/09/17      2012/11/22      
Matter Number: A4042005
A4042005        Tayerera    2011/09/17      2013/09/16      2012/11/27      
A4042005        Tayerera    2011/11/11      2013/11/10      2012/11/27      
A4042005        Tayerera    2011/11/11      2013/11/10      2012/11/27      
A4042005        Tayerera    2011/09/17      2013/09/16      2012/11/27      
Matter Number: A4042029
A4042029        Wallace     2011/09/17      2013/09/16      2013/01/21      
Matter Number: A4042188
A4042188        Khoza       2011/10/04      2013/10/04      2012/04/04      
Matter Number: A4042212
A4042212        Gocini      2011/09/30      2013/09/29      2012/10/29
```

Comment: If you'd like a quick and clear solution to the problem, please make sure your code actually works out of the box. That way we can quickly test whether our solution works for you before posting it here, without having to debug your code first.

Comment: My code works out the box, you can test it yourself by copying the code and downloading the spreadsheet from http://www.fileswap.com/dl/fRnQ6h61sy/ see for yourself. You also need to make sure that you have the Apache poi modules in your libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The tutorials contain examples](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html) how to create Excel files with POI. For your case, start with the "Timesheet" demo, it's probably closest to what you need.

Comment: here's my problem, i cannot specify the headings because of the fact that each spreadsheet i work with has different amounts of columns that's why i want to know if i can stream it straight in?

Comment: unless i can stream the data to a word file straight then i don't need to export it to an excel sheet, which theoretically should be easier.

Comment: @user1982690: Why the number of columns a problem? And how would streaming solve that?

Comment: streaming doesn't care about how many columns there are, as long as there is a next row value it will pull all the columns in that row so if you dealing with a huge data-set then you don't need to worry about how many cells there are in a row :) my logic behind it however i could be wrong.

Comment: Did you try to wrap the POI API in a helper class that collects all columns of a row, for example? Or do you have millions of columns? If so, consider using the XML Spreadsheet (XMLSS) schema (xslx format)

Comment: i have got it to work, yes i can go anywhere from 15 to 100 Columns easy depending on what is sent to me for processing

Comment: 100 columns shouldn't be an issue. Just collect the data model in memory and then use POI to write everything at once after grouping/sorting it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your advice this seems to be a better solution, i have run some tests with it and it works. However i need to revisit my actual program after im finished with my current  job.

Answer (score 1):

I edited my code to look like follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;


import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelGroupData {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
//create a input stream for your excel file from which data will be read.  
    FileInputStream excelSheetInput = new FileInputStream("C:/book2.xlsx");
    //POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(excelSheetInput);
    XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelSheetInput);
    //get first work sheet in your excel file.
    Sheet sheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
    //we will read data in first rows(0) second column(1)
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    Row myRow = sheet.getRow(1);
    Cell myCell= myRow.getCell(0);
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator ;
    String firstCell = myCell.getStringCellValue();
    int count =1;
    String nextCell;
    String Matter = "Matter Number: "+firstCell;
    String num = firstCell;
    System.out.println(Matter);
    FileWriter fWriter = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    fWriter = new FileWriter(num+".txt");
    writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
    writer.write(Matter);
    writer.newLine();
    while(rowIterator.hasNext())
    {


        myRow = sheet.getRow(count);
        cellIterator = myRow.cellIterator();
        myCell= myRow.getCell(0);
        nextCell= myCell.getStringCellValue();


        if(nextCell.equals(firstCell))
        {

            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                            switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                                    writer.write(cell.getStringCellValue()+ "\t");
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                                    writer.write(cell.getStringCellValue()+ "\t");
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
            System.out.println();
            writer.newLine();
            count++;

        }
        else
        {          
            writer.close();
            myRow = sheet.getRow(count);
            myCell= myRow.getCell(0);
            nextCell=myCell.getStringCellValue();
            firstCell=nextCell;
            Matter = "Matter Number: "+firstCell;
            num = firstCell;
            System.out.println(Matter);
            fWriter = new FileWriter(num+".txt");
            writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
            writer.write(Matter);
            writer.newLine();
        }

    }


}
}
```

This now writes each group to a text file, however its not writing the last group to the text file but the general concept is there.

Comment: The beauty about what has been done is that it can be edited to write to a csv file as well, so it give me flexibility in terms of a doc, rtf and txt file as well as some form of an excel output